# as3: random number fail in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, random, numbers

The following code is trying to assign, (on the spot made properties of bloodyParticle) forceX and forceY, random number.
But the problem is that random numbers are same for all the three instances being created.

```
for(var k:int = 0; k<3; k++)
{
    var bloodyParticle:BloodyParticle = new BloodyParticle();
    bloodyParticle.forceX = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
    bloodyParticle.forceY = Math.random() * -20 + 10;
    bloodyParticle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bloodyParticleLoop);
    bloodyParticle.x = bloodyPoint.x;
    bloodyParticle.y = bloodyPoint.y;
}
```

ok as per the comments, this is how i use them

```
private function bloodyParticleLoop(e:Event)
    {
        bloodyBmd.fillRect(bloodyBmd.rect, 0);
        bloodyBmd.draw(MovieClip(e.target),MovieClip(e.target).transform.matrix);
        //tried e.target also
        e.target.x += e.target.forceX;
        e.target.y += e.target.forceY;
        e.target.forceY++;
    }
```

and getter/setter of forceX and forceY was not there earlier but i just made it inside the class which looks like this now

package 
{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class BloodyParticle extends MovieClip
{
    public var forceX:Number;
    public var forceY:Number;


    public function BloodyParticle()
    {
        forceX = Math.random() * 20 - 5; //cz i hav the random number here-
        forceY = Math.random() * -20 + 10;//-i commented the earlier 
                                                      //-initialization of forceX/Y
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Should not. Did you try tracing actual values of `forceX` and `forceY`?

Comment: perhaps the error occurs where you get forceX/Y, rather than where you set them.

Comment: Could you show us the getter/setter for forceX/forceY?

Comment: i tried tracing and they all hav different values but all the objects of bloodyParticle are going in same direction..

Comment: added the getter/setter

Comment: i found the problem,
its because the line 3 of second code snippet.. it sets the bitmapdata clear before updating the position, so in the end it displays the last bloodyParticle..

THnx you guys 6_^